# Pass Objects to AutoMapper Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am working with AutoMapper and some of the values for the entity being mapped to are variables in my current method. I have tried to Google it but to no avail. Can I pass a set of KeyValue Pairs or an object or something to my mapping to have it use those values?

#### Sample of Post Mapping Modification

```
//comment variable is a Comment class instance
var imageComment = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Data.ImageComment>(comment);
//I want to pass in imageId so I dont have to manually add it after the mapping
imageComment.ImageId = imageId;
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

AutoMapper handles this key-value pair scenario out of the box.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(res => res.Context.Options.Items["Foo"]));
```

Then at runtime:

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => opt.Items["Foo"] = "Bar");
```

A bit verbose to dig into the context items but there you go.

Comment: Is there any ways to use the ResolveUsing with the ConstructUsing method?

Comment: Is it possible the `ResolveUsing` method no longer accepts a lambda with just the context as argument or am I missing an extension function? I had to define a lambda with `(input, output, memberValue, context)` as arguments before I could get it to work with Automapper 5.2. Of course, it could still be the compiler which can no longer figure out which overload it needs to use...

Comment: 5.x added overloads, and those overloads were adjusted so that you wouldn't get weird compile-time errors.

Comment: I get an error with res.Context - the source model doesn't contain a definition for context. Using .net core 2.0 and AutoMapper 6.2.1

Answer (score 49):

#### AutoMapper 9.0.0

As of version 8.0.0 the API of AutoMapper has been changed. In doing so `ResolveUsing` was consolidated with `MapFrom`. Take a look at the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/2809) for further information.

**Profile**

```
public class CoreProfile : Profile
{
    public CoreProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Bar,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(
                    (src, dst, _, context) => context.Options.Items["bar"]
                )
            );    
    }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(
    source,opt => {
        opt.Items["bar"] = "baz";
    }
);
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you write a few words about what's changed compared to the previous answer (Automapper 6.0.2).

Comment: @Razor23Donetsk, thanks for the hint. I have added the missing description of the changes between the versions.

Comment: @Razor23Donetsk The missing description is the `MapFrom()` operation (and several others) got new overloads that expose the resolution context to the mapping expression.

Comment: In Automapper 12.0.0 `context` doesn't have `Options` property. Instead `context.Items` is used.

Comment: Does anyone know if this works with `ProjectTo`?

Answer (score 40):

For Automapper 6.0.2:

**Profile:**

```
public class CoreProfile : Profile
{
    public CoreProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Foo,
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing(
                    (src, dst, arg3, context) => context.Options.Items["Foo"]
                )
            );
    }
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
    var result = Mapper.Map<PlanResult>(aa, opt => {
        opt.Items["Foo"] = 2;
        opt.Items["OtherFoo"] = 1000;
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Objects can be passed to the resolver with the `Items` Dictionary option. The standard API to do this is pretty verbose (as seen in the accepted answer) but can be simplified nicely using a few extension methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Map using a resolve function that is passed the Items dictionary from mapping context
/// </summary>
public static void ResolveWithContext<TSource, TDest, TMember, TResult>(
    this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDest, TMember> memberOptions, 
    Func<TSource, IDictionary<string, object>, TDest, TMember, TResult> resolver
) {
    memberOptions.ResolveUsing((src, dst, member, context) => resolver.Invoke(src, context.Items, dst, member));
}

public static TDest MapWithContext<TSource, TDest>(this IMapper mapper, TSource source, IDictionary<string, object> context, Action<IMappingOperationOptions<TSource, TDest>> optAction = null) {
    return mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>(source, opts => {
        foreach(var kv in context) opts.Items.Add(kv);
        optAction?.Invoke(opts);
    });
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
// Define mapping configuration
Mapper.CreateMap<Comment, ImageComment>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.ImageId,
        opt => opt.ResolveWithContext(src, items, dst, member) => items["ImageId"])
    );

// Execute mapping
var context = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ImageId", ImageId } };
return mapper.MapWithContext<TSource, TDest>(source, context);
```

If you have an object that you commonly need to pass to mapper resolvers (for example, the current user), you can go one step further and define more specialized extensions:

```
public static readonly string USER_CONTEXT_KEY = "USER";

/// <summary>
/// Map using a resolve function that is passed a user from the
/// Items dictionary in the mapping context
/// </summary>
public static void ResolveWithUser<TSource, TDest, TMember, TResult>(
    this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDest, TMember> memberOptions,
    Func<TSource, User, TResult> resolver
) {
    memberOptions.ResolveWithContext((src, items, dst, member) =>
        resolver.Invoke(src, items[USER_CONTEXT_KEY] as User));
}

/// <summary>
/// Execute a mapping from the source object to a new destination
/// object, with the provided user in the context.
/// </summary>
public static TDest MapForUser<TSource, TDest>(
    this IMapper mapper,
    TSource source,
    User user,
    Action<IMappingOperationOptions<TSource, TDest>> optAction = null
) {
    var context = new Dictionary<string, object> { { USER_CONTEXT_KEY, user } };
    return mapper.MapWithContext(source, context, optAction);
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
// Create mapping configuration
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.ResolveWithUser((src, user) src.Foo(user));

// Execute mapping
return mapper.MapWithUser(source, user);
```

Comment: You may want to update your answer for 8.0 since the replaced `ResolveUsing` with `MapFrom`
http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have these two objects:

```
public class ObjectA {
 public string Property1 { get; set; }
 public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
public class ObjectB {
 public string Property1 { get; set; }
 public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to copy an existing object of type `ObjectA` into a new object of type `ObjectB`, using AutoMapper you have to do this:

```
var objectA = new ObjectA { Property1 = "Hello, World!", Property2 = 1 }
var objectB = new ObjectB();

// Copy data from a to b
AutoMapper.Mapper
  .CreateMap<ObjectA, ObjectB>()
  .BeforeMap((source, dest) => { dest.ImageId = imageId });
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(objectA, objectB); // source, destination;

// Or:
var objectB = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ObjectB>(objectA);
```

Comment: Yea I have that part working. I basically have an additional property on `ObjectB` that isn't on `ObjectA` but is a variable in my controller that I want to pass to the mapping at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried using reflection? Can you post sample code please?

Comment: I've added "BeforeMap" example, you can use it to manage mapping.

Comment: So I basically redefine the map where I am going to use it? Sorry not normally a C# guy so still figuring it out

Comment: This is just as verbose as manually adding it after the mapping