# How do I map a custom property when mapping an IEnumerable<Source> to IEnumerable<Destination> using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Source class:

```cs
pubilc class Source {
    public string SourceProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Destination class

```cs
pubilc class Destination {
    public string SourceProperty { get; set; }
    public string ValueFromMappingContext { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper profile

```cs
public class CustomProfile : Profile {
    public CustomProfile(){
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    }
}
```

This is where my mapping takes place

```cs
string valueFromMappingContext = "This Value is common for all items in the destination collection";

IEnumerable<Source> sourceItems = GetSourceItems();

IEnumerable<Destination> destinationItems = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Destination>>(sourceItems);

// I don't want to do this. this is the part I'm looking to replace:
destinationItems.ForAll(d => d.ValueFromMappingContext = valueFromMappingContext);
```

Ccurrently I have another loop right after the Map() method to populate this property, but I feel like there should be an AutoMapper feature to do this.

If it was a single item, I could probably use AfterMap method, but this won't work for an IEnumerable. If the `ValueFromMappingContext` was known at creation of CustomProfile, or could be something that can be derived from Source, I could probably use ForMember within my profile.

But `ValueFromMappingContext` is only known at the context where the actual mapping takes place. And its not part of the `Source` object.

How can I map `valueFromMappingContext` to each `destinationItem.ValueFromMappingContext` property in the `destinationItems` collection using AutoMapper features? I'm using AutoMapper 10.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754133/10608418 might this be a solution you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you @Knoop, this is the specific answer from that thread that did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019540/1184584